# How to receive data in a Fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments

I want to receive data from an Activity to a Fragment. 
In an Activity is easy:

```
Bundle b = getIntent().getExtras();
String flag = b.getString("flag");
```

Ok, for me, doesn't work

```
String flag = getIntent().getExtras().getString("flag");
```

Neither

```
String flag = getActivity().getIntent().getExtras().getString("flag");
```

Or.

```
Bundle b = getIntent().getExtras();
```

The error: "Unreachable code"

Any idea?

Comment: you may have an if else chain that causes that piece of code to never run. Put a breakpoint on it and check it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can view that on [Fragment documentation](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments.html).

Create a `newInstance` funcion in your fragment to initialize the fragment and add data with `setArguments`, passing a `Bundle`.

```
public static DetailsFragment newInstance(int index) {
    DetailsFragment f = new DetailsFragment();

    // Supply index input as an argument.
    Bundle args = new Bundle();
    args.putInt("index", index);
    f.setArguments(args);

    return f;
}
```

Then get the arguments using:

```
 Bundle args = getArguments();
 int index = args.getInt("index", 0);
```